# Working with very small numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I have a simple program I'm trying to get to solve the problem of approximating the derivative of sin(x) + cos(x) at x=0. The formula for this is [f(x+h) + f(x)]/h  where x is 0, as stated, and I'm trying 6 different values for h: 10e-3, 10e-6, 10e-9, 10e-12, 10e-15, 10e-18. The following code works for all of them except 10e-18, but I can't figure out why.
10e-18 is small, but it doesn't seem like it should be that small. The output for the last h is 0, the rest are very close to 1, as they should be.

```
function fprime = twoPointForward(x)
h = 10e-3;
f = sin(x) + cos(x);



    for i=1:6;
        fprime = ((sin(x+h) + cos(x+h))-f)/h

        h=h/1000;

    end


end
```

I appreciate any help. All the other threads I found dealing with this have solutions that are more specific to their respective problems.

Comment: Because of the exact way in which floating point numbers are implemented this is going to cause a lot of problems. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You can see how small of a number Matlab can represent using `eps`. If `h` ever gets smaller than `eps(x)` you are going to have severe problems. In practice, try to use numbers at least few orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: 1e-18 isn't that small; it's plenty within the scope of the floating point exponent to represent. But cos(1e-18) \approx 1 - 1e-18, which is beyond the capability of floating point to represent accurately - the exponent is pinned by the 1 part, then the 1e-18 falls off the bottom of the mantissa.

Comment: Maybe this is not an option, but to point out the obvious -- you know you could do this symbolically: `cos(x) - sin(x)`? The reason you are having problems is because Subtracting nearly equal numbers is [badly behaved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to work with logarithms when h gets too small. However, is there really a reason for having `h=10^-18`. It seems that if this is a problem you should consider finding another apporach.

And regarding the error. In short, the computer have a floating point accuracy due to the hardware and matlab also have a floating point resolution due to the use of different types like double, float, ... More about that in the article reccommended by [shuttle87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942133/working-with-very-small-numbers-in-matlab#comment38761985_24942133)